# Strange behaviour in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Am having some behaviour I cannot understand why in my jqgrid.My **Add** , **Edit** and **Delete** buttons seem to have interchanged there respective urls.

```
$("#list").navGrid("#pager",                
    {add:true,addtext:'Add',edit:true,edittext:'Edit',del:true,deltext:'Delete'},               
    {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/add',closeAfterAdd:'true'},                                                       
    {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/edit',closeAfterEdit:'true'},
    {url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/delete',closeAfterAdd:'true'}
);
```

When I try **Add** from the interface firebug console shows that am actually **Editing**.
When I try **Edit** from the interface firebug console shows that am actually **Adding**.
Delete seems to be fine.

Are there defaults or something that am missing in my jqgrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [jqGrid Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator), the order of parameters is:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager',{parameters},
                           prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

The problem with your code is that you are passing the Add and Edit parameters in the wrong order. You need to re-order them:

```
$("#list").navGrid("#pager",                
    {add:true,addtext:'Add',edit:true,edittext:'Edit',del:true,deltext:'Delete'},
    {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'baseUrl() ?>/artist/edit',closeAfterEdit:'true'}, 
    {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'baseUrl() ?>/artist/add',closeAfterAdd:'true'},
    {url:'baseUrl() ?>/artist/delete',closeAfterAdd:'true'}
);
```